# Apple watch always displays the wrong high temperature

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, weather.app

I'm having trouble understanding the Apple watch high and low temperature values. They are never correct.

In Nyc, the high is going to be 81 today. However when I looked this morning it said 72 degrees.  When I scroll forward I get time travel to update the weather values. Somewhat.

Right now as I scroll the low value for the day is 57. But as I scroll the high value keeps changing.

Is this a bug?  What is the frame of reference? (High in the past hour, past day, etc)

Comment: I’ve noticed this problem when I wear my watch to bed. The high/low for the next day never seems to update then. But if I charge it overnight, things appear fine. Sometimes changing locations will cause the display to refresh properly, sometimes not. 3.2 seems to have improved things, but it’s hard to say for sure because the weather’s been fairly stable lately.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that this happens because of the delay introduced by the network and retrieving the temperature for your location.

Many things have to happen to show you the temperatures. I see this same thing on my iPhone but I think it's more noticeable on the Watch because you're staring at it, waiting for the data.   You can be looking at the old data while the app gets the latest updates and then the numbers will change as the new data rolls in.

In addition, some apps, such as Weather Underground, take an extremely long time to do their updates. I've even given-up using some weather apps because of this delay.